# override two diffrent size image in openCV android

Tags: android, opencv

can anyone help me to override one transparent image on another image in 
  OpenCV Android?  I have done the following code. its work for same size image but I want on two different size image

```
Bitmap bitmap_a1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.a1);
Bitmap bitmap_a2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.a2);

Mat mat_a1 = new Mat();
Mat mat_a2 = new Mat();

Mat mat_combine = new Mat();
Mat mat_cropped = new Mat();

int w = bitmap_a1.getWidth();
int h = bitmap_a1.getHeight();
bitmap_combine = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap_a1,mat_a1);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap_a2,mat_a2);
Core.addWeighted(mat_a1,1,mat_a2,0.9,0.0,mat_combine);
Utils.matToBitmap(mat_combine,bitmap_combine);
iv_open.setImageBitmap(bitmap_combine);
```

Comment: The main problem would be, how it is suppose to overcome the difference in sizes? will it be resized to fit the other image (or viceversa), will you add padding, and if so to which side?  will you crop the bigger image? and if so, which side will be cropped?

Comment: i want small mask image on Big image . hear small image is transpernt...Help me

Comment: yes, but in which part of the big image will it be?

Comment: i want movable image block on big image ..user can move block of small image then user selected position image have to overide